# Can I install KDE Plasma 6 on Ubuntu 22.04 or should I wait for Kubuntu Kubuntu 24.10?

Tags: kde

I am a noob and currently using Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome.

I'm not a fan of Gnome and KDE Plasma 6, which just came out, really speaks to me.

Since it wille take some time till Kubuntu 24.10 with Plasma 6 comes out, I wanted to ask, whether it's fine if I just install Plasma 6 on Ubuntu 22.04 myself or if it would be better to wait for the Kubuntu 24.10 release.

Comment: To use KDE Plasma 6, you'll need to upgrade your software stack (especially Qt & KF) which can create problems with your non-KDE Plasma software found in Ubuntu *jammy* repositories.  Whilst most 22.04 repo software will use Qt5 & KF5 (not Qt6/KF6) most will not have problems.  Some QA has been done on *noble* (what will be 24.04 on release), that wasn't done on your *jammy* or 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the kde neon is on Ubuntu LTS version so, you just add the kde neon repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://archive.neon.kde.org/user bionic main'
wget -qO - 'http://archive.neon.kde.org/public.key' | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install plasma-desktop plasma-nm plasma-pa
```

Comment: This might have unforeseen consequences...

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to wait till Kubuntu 24.10 comes out, as they will have fixed many bugs by then.